Luke 22:42: why a cup?

Luke 22:42 says  saying, “Father, if you are willing, remove this
cup from me. Nevertheless, not my will, but yours, be done.

Why the word cup? what is the meaning of cup here?

The metaphorical cup can hold either joy or bitterness, pleasure or suffering. In Psalm 23, attributed to David, the poet sang:

You set a table before me
in front of my enemies; You anoint my head with oil;
my cup overflows.

Here, the opposite situation applies. Jesus was asked to drink from a bitter cup. His disciples had fallen asleep at the watch, and his enemies were about to capture and kill him.
We may also think of the parable of the Wedding Feast, in which those invited refused to come. As the Bridegroom, Jesus had invited his people to receive him as their Messiah (anointed one) but he was not accepted and had to go the Way of the Cross.
Conclusion: the cup is a symbol, containing the sweet wine of joy or the vinegary wine of suffering. In Psalm 23 it is joy. Here it is pain and rejection.

As opposed to what? In Revelation 17, the Harlot has a cup, " She held a golden cup in her hand, filled with abominable things and the filth of her adulteries." So doesn't everyone have a cup and fill it with either love or judgement? Isn't Jesus talking about the cup of judgement he is already beginning to receive?

The cup refers to a receiving action, and in this case suffering.
Drinking from a cup meant receiving and ingesting what is contained within it, and Christ was receiving suffering. He was asking the Father if the cup of suffering could pass away from him, but out of humility and understanding, only whatever was the Father's will for him and not his own will be done.
If the Father wanted him to stay with that cup, he would stay with it. If not, then he could be relieved of his suffering.
The meaning here is that God is the one who decides what cup we drink from, and we cannot decide for ourselves from what cup to drink. Only God decides what we drink from at any given point of our lives.

Romans 8:28
All things work out for the good of those who love Him.


Will add more when I get time.

ποτήριον, ου, τό (dim. of ποτήρ [πίνω]; Alcaeus, Sappho, Hdt.+) a vessel used for drinking, cup (in Gk. lit. mostly for drinking of wine)... ⓑ fig. (in the OT ποτήριον is an expr. for destiny in both good and bad senses, for death in general TestAbr A 1 al. On the concept of drinking a cup of suffering cp. Is 51:17, 22; La 4:21; Ps 10:6; 74:9. ... —
--
Arndt, W., Danker, F. W., Bauer, W., & Gingrich, F. W. (2000). In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature (3rd ed., p. 857). University of Chicago Press.


Always God's wrath was taken through drinking, He said if your disobeying you will all drink my wrath.that's why Jesus called it a cup

The question is somewhat trim, so your answer needs to include as much Biblical support as possible, though in retrospect I'm not certain the question is as clear and delineated as it needs to be. In the future, please base your answers upon Biblical references and even quotes in context.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
